# How to read nested json file with python pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

i have a json structure as this one:

```
{"results":{"whatever_name":{"id":77},"another_name":{"id":89},"another_name":{"id":60}},"timestamp":123456}
```

the number of observations for each line is different, it might be 3 or whatever. I tried to use pandas pd.read_json but gives the obvious error, there are no common fields in the structure.
Can anyone help me to read the file in a dataframe with four fields: name, id, value, timestamp.

Comment: Flattened to how exactly? Can you give an example of the flattened json?

Comment: Sounds like a dupe. Is this what you want: `pd.io.json.json_normalize(JSONSTRING)` ?

Comment: if a use pd.io.json.json_normalize(string) i get the following error:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: No need to be rude. Nobody here gets paid to help, we do it because we like to help. Please read this [mcve] and [ask] and be nice.

Comment: Anton vBR that message was not meant for you. but for the guy who wrote that this question is a duplicate. He eventually erased his comment.